# How do I add the legend of each layer to my ggplot map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am creating a map with different provinces and have 4 point layers over this map each from their own source. When I add the layers to create the map, I only get a legend for the provinces of the map, not for the rest of the layers.

```r
Province %>% group_by(ProvinceNa) %>% 
  summarize() %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_sf(aes(fill = ProvinceNa)) + 
    scale_fill_grey() +
    geom_sf(data = It, col = "yellow") + 
    geom_sf(data = Io, col = "blue") +
    geom_sf(data = Ib, col = "brown") +
    geom_sf(data = Ie, col = "green")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a legend map on aesthetics, i.e. use e.g. `geom_sf(data = It, aes(color = "yellow"))`. To get the right colors add `scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")`.

**EDIT** To change the labels you could pass a named vector to the `labels` argument of `scale_color_identity` to assign color names to labels.

Making use of the default example data from `?ggplot2::geom_sf`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc, aes(fill = AREA)) +
  geom_sf(data = nc, aes(colour = "yellow"), fill = NA) +
  scale_color_identity(labels = c(yellow = "Yellow Label"), guide = "legend")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I did it and it worked, except now the labels are the color names instead of the layer names. How do I change that?

Comment: That is easily fixed. See my edit on how you could assign labels to color names.

Comment: Is there a way of adding the title for the legend? When I add name = "title" or title = "title" in the scale_color_identity brackets, is doesn't show.

Comment: Hm. `scale_color_identity(name = "title", ...)` should work .I just checked on my example.

Answer (score 0):

[image: map]

This is my coding:

```
Province %>% group_by(ProvinceNa) %>% 
summarize() %>% 
ggplot() + 
geom_sf(aes(fill = ProvinceNa)) + scale_fill_grey("Provinces") +
geom_sf(data=It, aes(col = "yellow")) + 
geom_sf(data=Io, aes(col = "blue")) +
geom_sf(data=Ib, aes(col = "Brown")) +
geom_sf(data=Ie, aes(col="green")) +
scale_color_identity(name = "Species", labels = c(yellow = "Ichnochiton textilis", blue = "Ichnochiton oniscus", Brown = "Ischnochiton bergoti", green = "Ischnochiton elizabethensis"),guide = "legend")
```

Comment: It's as if the title is cut off

Comment: Hi Karlien. Hm. That's a different issue. There is nothing wrong with the code. The point is that "R" does it's best to fit your plot into the plotting device. But sometimes that isn't possible so your plot gets cut off. There are at least two options: a) Increase the height of the plotting window or the height used when saving the plot, b) try with horizontal legends, c) ...

Comment: ... and BTW: If you want to add code or an image then add it as an edit to your original post. Not as an answer.